# Solve the differential equation $xy'+2y=4x^2, y(0)=8.$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $xy'+2y=4x^2, y(0)=8.$

**My attempt:**

I found the integrating factor as $x^2$.
Integrating,
I got the general solution $$x^2y=x^4+C.$$
I applied the initial condition $x=0,y=8$. I got $C=0$.
But in the textbook, They say that solution doesn't exist. Could you explain?

Comment: With $C=0$, the solution you got will be $y=x^2$ and this does not satisfy the initial condition $y(0)=8$, hence no solution. In fact, you can easily see that without even solving the DE by testing the initial condition in the given DE (at $x=0$, we get $y=0$).

Comment: Indeed $0y'(0)+2y(0)=4\cdot0^2\implies y(0)=0.$

Comment: @anurag, How will you divide by zero?  when C=0, we get $x^2y=x^4$.

Comment: @Unknownx for the integrating factor you would have written the DE as $y'+\frac{2}{x}y=4x$, so you have already made the assumption that $x \neq 0$.

Comment: As you get $x^2y=x^4+C$ you can rewrite it as $y=x^2+\frac{C}{x^2}$ and evaluating in $x=0$ you're dividing by zero so there's no solution with the initial value $y(0)=8$